# ColdFusion 10 error with Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion, sql-server-2012, coldfusion-10

In a .CFC file, within a CFfunction and with CFargument tags.

```
    <cfscript>
        var sp=new storedproc();
        sp.setDatasource(variables.datasource);
        sp.setProcedure("storedProcedure_INSERT");
        sp.addParam(cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer",type="in",value=arguments.one);
        sp.addParam(cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer",type="in",value=arguments.two);
        sp.addParam(cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer",type="in",value=arguments.three);
        sp.addParam(cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer",type="in",value=arguments.four);
        sp.addProcResult(name="results",resultset=1);
        //writeDump(sp);break;  //This dump is reached
        var spObj=sp.execute(); //blows up here; this is never reached
        writeDump(spObj);break; //This is never reached, either.
        var spResults=spObj.getProcResultSets().results;
```

A shiny nickle to anyone who can tell me why the sp.execute() is blowing up with message

```
"Cannot find results key in structure.

The specified key, results, does not exist in the structure."
```

I've used this psuedo-code many, may times in the past, and never had it do this.  I'm connected to a MSSQL Server 2012 DB, everything's cricket in CF Admin, and other SPs are working properly.  The stack trace doesn't even include any of MY code at all o_O

> The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/base.cfc: line 491
>   Called from C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/storedproc.cfc: line 142
>   Called from //hq-devfs/development$/websites/myProject/cfc/mySOAPWSDLs.cfc: line 123

And SO is blowing up if I try and paste anymore of that.  Google has...not been helpful ._.

Comment: Does the stored procedure execute from SSMS?  If so, does it run using <cfstoredproc> and associated tags?

Comment: Silly question, but given the name of the procedure - does it actually return a resultset ie Query object?

Comment: That's not ACTUALLY the name of it; I'm trying to avoid putting anything too specific to my employer in here.  What it does is it takes the params, looks for an existing record, updates it if there is one or inserts if not.  Either way, though, it should return the number of rows affected, no?

Comment: Of course. Still, the name implies the procedure is performing an INSERT action and that is relevant here. *it should return the number of rows affected, no* No. A resultset means a query. That is different than the number of rows affected. That is why you are getting an error. The code is telling CF to retrieve a resultset, but the proc does not actually return one.

Comment: I only use tags but if addProcResult is the equivalent of <cfprocresult>, then no.  It expects a query object.  Does your SP do that?

Comment: @DanBracuk I added RETURN @@rowcount to the end of the SP and still getting the error.

Comment: RETURN does not generate a "query" ie resultset. Only SELECT statements do. It sounds like what you are looking for is the equivalent of `<cfstoredproc result="myResult" ..>`, which I believe would be `spObj.getPrefix()`.  However, I do not know if either the tag or cfscript version includes "number of rows affected". Probably not, since stored procedure can execute multiple statements, each one potentially generating a count. So I suspect that key is not include in the "result" or "prefix".

Comment: @Janet - Change the `RETURN` to `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS NumRowsAffected` and your original code will work.

Comment: Good! I am going to write up a fuller explanation as an answer. Primarily because a) comments are temporary and can be deleted and b) I think understanding *why* it does not work with inserts might be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @Leigh Good idea, because I can't mark my own Answer as an Answer for hours yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** The error means you are trying to retrieve a resultset from the stored procedure, when it does not actually return one. A simple solution is to add a `SELECT` to the end of your procedure, so it returns a resultset containing the data you need. Then your original code will work:

```
   SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS NumOfRowsAffected;
```

**Longer answer:**
The method you are using, `addProcResult()`, is the equivalent of [`<cfprocresult>`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfprocresult). It is intended to capture a [resultset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Result_set) returned from a stored procedure. (Due to CF's poor choice of attribute names, a lot of people think "resultset" means the storedproc "result" structure, but they are two totally different things). A "resultset" is a query object", in CF parlance.

While all four (4) of the primary sql statements return *some* result, not all of them return a "query object"

- Only `SELECT` statements generate a "query object"
- `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements simply return the number of rows affected. They do not generate a  "query object".

Since your stored procedure performs an `INSERT`, it does not generate a "query object". Hence the error when you try and grab the non-existent query here:

```
  sp.addProcResult(name="results",resultset=1);
```

The simple solution is to add a `SELECT` statement to the end of your stored procedure, so that it *does* return a query object. Then your code will work as expected.

---

As an aside, I suspect you were actually trying to grab the "result" structure, but used the wrong method.  The equivalent of `<cfstoredproc result="..">` is `getPrefix()`. Though that would not work here anyway. According to [the docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/storedproc), it does not contain the number of rows affected. Probably because stored procedures can execute multiple statements, each one potentially returning a row count, so there is not just a single value to return.